# How does requests' stream=True option streams data one block at a time?

Tags: python, http, tcp, python-requests

I'm using the following code to test how many seconds an HTTP connection can be kept alive:

```
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
      r = requests.get(BIG_FILE_URL, stream=True)
      total_length = r.headers['Content-length']
      for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE): 
        time.sleep(1)
    # ... except and more logic to report total time and percentage downloaded
```

To be sure Python doesn't just download everything at once and creates a generator, I've used tcpdump. It does send one packet per second (approximately) but I didn't find what makes the server send one block at a time and how does the requests library does that.

I've checked several SOF questions and looked at the requests library documentation, but all resources explain how to use the library to download large files, and none of them explain the internals of the stream=True option.

My question is: what in the tcp protocol or HTTP request headers, makes the server send one block at a time and not the whole file at once?

### EDIT + possible answer:

After working with Wireshark, I found out Python implements it using the TCP's sliding window. Meaning, it won't send an ack while the next chunk is not called.

That might cause some unexpected behavior as the sliding window might be a lot bigger than the chunk, and the chunks in the code might not represent actual packets.
Example: if you set the chunk to 1000 bytes, a default sliding window of 64K (my default on Ubuntu 18) will cause 64 chunks to be sent immediately. If the body size is less than 64K the connection might close immediately. So this is not a good idea for keeping connection online.

Comment: Can you post the relevant tcp stream? It will help to see the request and response headers in question...

Answer (score 32):

This is not explained in user documentation.
By going through the source code of `requests`, I found out that if we set `stream=True` in `requests.get(...)` then  `headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'` is set in the HTTP headers. Thus specifying the Chunked transfer encoding. In chunked transfer encoding, the data stream is divided into a series of non-overlapping "chunks". The chunks are sent out independently of one another by the server.
Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does makes sense but using Wireshark, I don't see any Transfer-Encoding header at all...

Comment: I see only Host, User-Agent, Accept-Encoding, Accept and Connection headers

Comment: What http version is it?

Comment: http 1.1 @tarique

Comment: What's the response header looks like?

Comment: Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 18:43:01 GMT  
Connection: keep-alive  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
Content-Length: 583404

Comment: `if files:
                raise NotImplementedError('Streamed bodies and files are mutually exclusive.')

            if length:
                self.headers['Content-Length'] = builtin_str(length)
            else:
                self.headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'` this is the source code of request.

Comment: @Tom Is `Transfer-Encoding` in `r.headers`? Maybe you've pasted a wrong HTTP header. If `Content-Length` is in the headers, then it means that the request was not chunked. Can you filter it out in Wireshark by `http.transfer_encoding == "chunked"`? Possibly, your issue stems from [a bug](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1648) if you're using an older version of requests.

Comment: Great. It would be nice if you provide a link to that part of the code you found in document.

Comment: https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/sessions.py

Comment: The latest documentation says that you only get chunked incoming/outgoing requests if you use "a generator (or any iterator without a length)" for the request body. See more in here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests

Answer (score 15):

This question caught my curiosity, so I decided to go down this research rabbit hole. Here are some of my (open to corrections!) findings:

- Client to server communication is standardized by the Open Systems Interconnection model ( [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) ).
- The transfer of data is handled by layer 4 - the Transport Layer. TCP/IP always breaks the data into packets. The IP packet lengths max out at approx. [65.5K bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure).

  Now what keeps Python from recombining all these packets into the original file before returning it?
  The requests `iter_content`method has a nested generator which wraps a urllib3 generator method: `class urllib3.response.HTTPResponse(...).stream(...)`

  The 'chunk_size' parameter seems to set a buffer for how much data is read from the open socket into memory before it's written to the file system.

  Here's a copy of the `iter_content` method that was helpful:

```
def iter_content(self, chunk_size=1, decode_unicode=False):
        """Iterates over the response data.  When stream=True is set on the
        request, this avoids reading the content at once into memory for
        large responses.  The chunk size is the number of bytes it should
        read into memory.  This is not necessarily the length of each item
        returned as decoding can take place.

        chunk_size must be of type int or None. A value of None will
        function differently depending on the value of `stream`.
        stream=True will read data as it arrives in whatever size the
        chunks are received. If stream=False, data is returned as
        a single chunk.

        If decode_unicode is True, content will be decoded using the best
        available encoding based on the response.
        """

        def generate():
            # Special case for urllib3.
            if hasattr(self.raw, 'stream'):
                try:
                    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
                        yield chunk
                except ProtocolError as e:
                    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
                except DecodeError as e:
                    raise ContentDecodingError(e)
                except ReadTimeoutError as e:
                    raise ConnectionError(e)
            else:
                # Standard file-like object.
                while True:
                    chunk = self.raw.read(chunk_size)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    yield chunk

            self._content_consumed = True

        if self._content_consumed and isinstance(self._content, bool):
            raise StreamConsumedError()
        elif chunk_size is not None and not isinstance(chunk_size, int):
            raise TypeError("chunk_size must be an int, it is instead a %s." % type(chunk_size))
        # simulate reading small chunks of the content
        reused_chunks = iter_slices(self._content, chunk_size)

        stream_chunks = generate()

        chunks = reused_chunks if self._content_consumed else stream_chunks

        if decode_unicode:
            chunks = stream_decode_response_unicode(chunks, self)
          

 return chunks
```